# Add padding if element is not table

Tags: element, css-tables

This is my CSS cut:

```
html, body, * {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}
```

I need to modify it, so if any table has a `cellpadding="4"` attribute, then it won't add `padding:0;` to that and will use this attribute instead : `cellpadding="4"`.

Is it possible?

Comment: `html, body, *` is a bit redundant, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to use padding:inherit; also, declare it after your html,body,* line.

```
html, body, * {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}
table[cellpadding="4"] {
    padding:inherit;    
}
```

### UPDATE

If your cells are being affected by your * css code, you can include a line specifically for td elements:

```
table[cellpadding="4"] td {
    padding:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers support the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Anot) selector. Usage:

```
*:not([cellpadding]) {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rWVEu/**

Comment: That would apply the padding to the actual table, whereas the `cellpadding` attribute is applied to table cells.

Comment: @animuson Then use the `:not()` selector (supported by all major browsers). See updated answer.

Comment: My HTML for table looks like: `<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" width="100%">` and when I replaced my `html, body, * {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}` with one you've posted, it not worked (I mean it's not using original table padding). The code that @bozdoz posted seems to not work properly too, because I need to use for example: `padding: 4px;` instead of `padding: inherit;`